# Does PDT transfer with you when you switch brokerages?

Tags: united-states, stocks, broker, day-trading, regulation

Robinhood classified me as a Pattern Day Trader (PDT). If I switch to TD Ameritrade, will my 90 day ban follow me?

Worried that if I make a trade with TD Ameritrade then I try to sell it will immediately block me. I don't have $25,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDT designation should not follow you across brokerages. Many traders utilize this fact by opening accounts with multiple brokerages; so they can complete multiple day trades across their accounts without triggering the PDT designation in any one account (for accounts valued under $25000).

If for some reason TD Ameritrade does transfer the designation for you, you should be able to remove the designation by making your account a cash account.